# Why does the Python Secrets module keep generating the same passwords in this function in Django

Tags: python, django, random, passwords, secrets

Here is the function:

```
def generate_password():
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "!@#$%^&*()+=/.,"
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(12))
```

I added this to a Django model, so that it is automatically called when creating a user, and automatically generates its password.
This is the code in the model:

```
password = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=generate_password())
```

For some reason, creating 4 users is always going to create at least one duplicate password, if not two.

this is an example of the passwords generated by creating 7 users:

PpN(ky^tabgP
iIS@4gfe@7sc
6#oNlIH0MbQg
6#oNlIH0MbQg
iIS@4gfe@7sc
PpN(ky^tabgP
PpN(ky^tabgP

This approach was suggested by different people and documentation, yet it seems like this function is always cycling between only a few passwords, and keeps repeating them.

Can anyone help me understand why and how to avoid it?

Django needs to be restarted some times so adding passwords to a set is not convenient.

Comment: Can you show the code that *adds `generate_password` to the django model?*

Comment: Does the issue also occur without django?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I just added that to the description

Comment: `default=generate_password()` is the problem.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no, this seems to be a commonly used method to generate password, and without Django there is no repeating

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM how so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
password = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=generate_password())
```

It must be(without *parentheses*)

```
password = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=generate_password)
```

because you need to pass a callable object as [`default` argument and  it will be called by django when every time a new object is created.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#default)

But that's not the case with your current code. Since you are using parentheses `()`, the function `generate_password` immediately gets invoked and return value gets assigned to the `default`.

Comment: Thank you, I am testing this answer right now and will accept if it works as soon as I'm done.

Could you elaborate a bit on this point for me please? I can't really understand the issue:

"because you need to pass a callable object as default argument and it will be called every time a new object is created."

I would understand if this resulted in an error, but since the function is being called, what is the difference that causes the passwords to repeat?

Comment: @Xandro You can pass a string or a callable as an argument to `default`. Your current code is equivalent to passing a static string to `default` which will be using for all objects. But that's not the case if you pass a callable object.

Comment: But in that case wouldn't the password always be the same? I'm still trying to understand